# Counting steps in the collatz conjecture

Tags: python

I want to know the total steps needed to get from n (in the example 15) to 1.
This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    c = 0
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            c += 1
            yield(n)
            yield ('{%d}' % c)
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            c += 1
            yield(n)
            yield ('{%d}' % c)


print(list(collatz(15)))
```

This is what I get. It gives me all steps, but I need only their total number (in the example 17) .

```
[46, '{1}', 23, '{2}', 70, '{3}', 35, '{4}', 106, '{5}', 53, '{6}', 160, '{7}', 80, '{8}', 40, '{9}', 20, '{10}', 10, '{11}', 5, '{12}', 16, '{13}', 8, '{14}', 4, '{15}', 2, '{16}', 1, '{17}']
```

Comment: Wait, what is `c` in this example? It's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `reverse` the `list`:

```
print(reversed(list(collatz(15))))
```

and to get the last number:

```
print(list(collatz(15))[-1]) #for '{17}'
print(list(collatz(15))[-2]) #for 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't contaminate your output with the count.  Instead, count the elements in the iterable from outside the iterable.

```
def collatz(n):
 while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
        yield(n)
    else:
        n = n * 3 + 1
        yield(n)

print(len(list(collatz(15))))  # More obvious what's happening
# 17
print(sum(1 for _ in collatz(15)))  # Doesn't keep a list of results we don't care about
# 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
def collatz(n):
    var = 0
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
           n = n // 2
           var  += 1
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            var += 1
    return var

print(collatz(32)) # output --> 5
```